# A* pathfinding on 2D grid doesn't find optimal path

Tags: python, python-2.7, 2d, path-finding, a-star

I am trying to implement the A* algorithm on a 2D square grid. However, it almost never finds an optimal path, and I just can't see why. The code is also suspiciously slow, even for python.

I've tried just anything, I'm out of ideas.

This is what I have so far:

file astar.py:

```
end = None

NLUT = [ (1,0) , (0,1) , (-1,0) , (0,-1) ]

class Tile:
    def __init__(self,x,y,g=0,parent=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.g = g
        self.parent = parent

    def __eq__(self,other):
        if other == None:
            return False
        return ( (self.x == other.x) and (self.y == other.y))
    def __ne__(self,other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x,self.y))

    def __str__(self):
        if self.parent == None:
            sss = ""
        else:
            sss = " <- "+str(self.parent.coords())
        return "<"+str(self.x)+"."+str(self.y)+"g"+str(self.g)+">"+sss
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<"+str(self.x)+"."+str(self.y)+">"

    def coords(self):
        return (self.x,self.y)

    def f(self):
        return self.g + self.h()

    def h(self):
        global end
        return ((abs(self.x-end[0]) + abs(self.y-end[1])))

    def nbd(self):
        global NLUT
        return [ Tile(self.x + n[0], self.y + n[1], self.g + 1, self) for n in NLUT]



def pathfind(mapfunction,start,endp):

    global end
    end = endp
    DEBUG = False
#   DEBUG = True


    def log(st):
        if DEBUG:
            print(st)

    startile = Tile(start[0],start[1],0)
    endtile = Tile(end[0],end[1])

    path = []

    # init openSet with the starting tile
    openSet = set([startile])
    closedSet = set()

    stepcount = 0

    #the loop, as long as openSet is not empty:
    while len(openSet)>0:

        log(str(stepcount)+"-"+str(openSet))
        stepcount += 1
        fcur = float("inf")
        #find lowest f-count tile in the open set
        for o in openSet:
            if o.f() < fcur:
                fcur = o.f()
                current = o

        log("current: "+str(current))

        #move the current tile to the closed set
        openSet.remove(o)
        closedSet.add(o)

        #find the von neumann neighbourhood
        nbd = o.nbd()
        log("nbd: "+str(nbd))
        #work on the neighbours
        for n in nbd:

            log("processing "+str(n))


            if mapfunction(n.x,n.y) != 0: #if it's blocked, ignore
                log("it was blocked.")
                continue
            elif n in closedSet: #if it's in the closed set, ignore
                log("it was in the closed set.")
                continue
            elif n in openSet: #if it's in the open set...
                log("it's in the open set...")
                for e in openSet: 
                    if n==e:            #find the old copy of n in the open set
                        if n.g < e.g:   #if it's a better path, substitute
                            log("SUBSTITUTION")
                            openSet.remove(e)
                            openSet.add(n)
                        else:
                            log("old path was better.")

                        break           #no need to go on...
            else: #if it's not in the open set, add it
                log("not in the open set, adding...")
                openSet.add(n)


        if endtile in closedSet:          #if we're done
            #find copy of endtile in closedSet
            for e in closedSet:
                if e == endtile:
                    rec = e
            while (not rec == None) and rec != startile:  #reconstruct the path
                path.append(rec.coords())
                rec = rec.parent
            path.append(startile.coords())
            return path  
    #if openset is empty, no path was found. :(        
    return -1
```

and this is a little demo program, astardemo.py:

```
import astar
from random import *

mapp = [[randint(0,10)//10 for _ in range(0,50)] for _ in range(0,50)]

def isblocked(x,y):
    global mapp

    if not (x in range(0,50) and y in range(0,50)):
        return 1
    return (mapp[x][y] != 0)

start = (randint(0,49),randint(0,49))
end = (randint(0,49),randint(0,49))

mapp[start[0]][start[1]] = 0
mapp[end[0]][end[1]] = 0

p = astar.pathfind(isblocked,start,end)

print p

l = ""

for i in range(0,50):
    for j in range(0,50):
        if (i,j) in p:
            if mapp[i][j] > 0:
                l+="E"
            else:
                l+=str(p.index((i,j))%10)

        elif mapp[i][j] > 0:
            l+="#"
        else:
            l+=" "
    l+="\n"
print l
```

Comment: Pick better names. `f`, `g`, and `h` on the same object, but `g` is an instance attribute and `f` and `h` are methods? What do these letters mean?

Comment: You mix up `current` and `o` a bunch of times. That could be your problem, or one of your problems.

Comment: Oh God, you're right. I used o instead of current. That's why it worked as if there was no f(), it just chose always the last tile on the openSet. Anyways, g is the path distance, h is the heuristic, and f is their sum. h and f are methods because I saw no point in keeping an array of h-values, since they are simply manhattan distances. Thanks for the quick answers

Comment: @user2357112 `f(x), g(x), and h(x)` are the core values in A* search The names are fine if you know A*, otherwise heuristic and CSF might be better variable names

Answer (score 0):

```
    for o in openSet:
        if o.f() < fcur:
            fcur = o.f()
            current = o

    log("current: "+str(current))

    #move the current tile to the closed set
    openSet.remove(o)
    closedSet.add(o)

    #find the von neumann neighbourhood
    nbd = o.nbd()
```

In this code you use `o` but you are outside the loop, so it will always be the last value in the loop did you mean to use `current`?

```
    for o in openSet:
        if o.f() < fcur:
            fcur = o.f()
            current = o

    log("current: "+str(current))

    #move the current tile to the closed set
    openSet.remove(current)
    closedSet.add(current)

    #find the von neumann neighbourhood
    nbd = current.nbd()
```

Comment: It *has* access to it. Simply it will only be the last value of the iteration.